# Limit of $\arcsin(x)$

Tags: limits

Suppose I want to find out $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \lceil \arcsin (x)\rceil$   where $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ denotes greatest integer function.

Now suppose I calculate the left hand limit which gives $\lceil \frac\pi2\rceil=1$
but when calculating the right hand limit as $x \to 1$ the value goes outside the domain of $\arcsin$,    which literally means the right hand limit doesn't   exist.

But textbooks say that the limit does exist
and is 1.

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

The natural domain of $f(x)=\sin^{-1} x$ is $[-1,1]$ so if you are computing limit as $x \to 1$, then the values that $x$ will take should only be considered that are within the natural domain. So in this case $\lim_{x \to 1}$ should be thought of as $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}$.

The two-sided limit only comes into play when the natural domain has both the left and right hand values with respect to the point in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\arcsin : [-1,1] \to [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. In particular if you have a sequence which converges to 1, then  your points are in $[-1,1]$, so you always take the 'left' limit.